# Consumer WebService in S/4HANA ABAP

Tags: web-services, wsdl, abap

I am a new developer on SAP and I perform a task that requires the consumption of a Web Service. But when I download the WSDL file from my local environment, I have some activation issues. Indeed I cannot activate it because there is a recursivity (recursion) in a method. ABAP does not take recursions into account unless translating it to `XSDany` and I don't know how I can no longer modify the WSDL file since it belongs to another service. Thanks in advance .

Comment: what sort of recursion? give service definition and error text in SAP

Answer (score 0):

SAP has a lot of limitation about WSDL. You can download and edit WSDL locally then use it for service creation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did not understand this notion of creating it because the file was sent to me by my colleagues from another service in order to add a new functionality between SAP4Hana and their application which is external.

Comment: mkysoft is suggesting you edit the WSDL you received to simplify it.
ABAP as webservice consumer has many limitations. Sometimes modifying the WSDL  is necessary.   Ive had to "Manually manipulate" the string being sent. It can get very tricky for complex unsupported services. Alternatively ask the service provider if they can simplify their service.